# Lua error while adding characters to write on file

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a ESP8266 module with nodemcu firmware that must be programmed using lua.
I wrote some code to save username/password credentials that are entered from a html page in a file.

This is the lua function and it works fine

```
   function parse_wifi_credentials(vars)
    if vars == nil or vars == "" then
        return false
    end

  local _, _, wifi_ssid = string.find(vars, "wifi_ssid\=([^&]+)")
  local _, _, wifi_password = string.find(vars, "wifi_password\=([^&]+)")

    if wifi_ssid == nil or wifi_ssid == "" or wifi_password == nil then
        return false
    end

    pwd_len = string.len(wifi_password)
    if pwd_len ~= 0 and (pwd_len < 8 or pwd_len > 64) then
        return false
    end

   file.open("credentials.txt", "a")
   file.write(wifi_ssid)
   file.write(wifi_password)
   file.flush()
   file.close()

    return true
end
```

It all works but my output file is something like

```
usernamepasswordotherusernameotherpassword
```

So I inserted values to separate fields like

```
 file.write(wifi_ssid)
 file.write(":")
 file.write(wifi_password)
```

and many other ways like this but my code does not work on my ESP8266 because I get `not enough memory` error but if I don't print the `:` I have something like 10 kb free.

I also tried  `file.write(wifi_ssid, "\n")` and it works but the output doesn't change.

Annyone knows what should I do to insert a character beetwen fields?

Comment: What version of the firmware do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
file.writeline(wifi_ssid)
```

to use end of line char at the file line.

To be sure about if file open causing out of mem problem due to its garbage content, you can delete it first and re-write the credentials.

Also it is good to have **collectgarbage()** method after your file.writeln or flush operations.

Comment: Could you please try it wih some garbage collection? Please add collectgarbage() after each file.writeline and flush?

Comment: Also i suggest to delete your file before write. Possible garbage would be filled into it while your trials.

Comment: Btw i do no not need any flush method for my programs.

Comment: i tried both of them, I guess it can be a firmware problem